# Change font style using shared preferences

Tags: java, android, fonts, styles

Code

```
Button mButton1;
String mDefaultFont1;
SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences1;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor1;

 mButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontextfontsent);
 mSharedPreferences1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 mDefaultFont1 = mSharedPreferences1.getString("Default_Font1","Normal");
 mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);

mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final String[] list = new String[]{"Normal", "Bold", "Italic", "Bold ITalic"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomizeFont.this);
        builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
        builder.setItems(list, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item==0) mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);
                if (item==1) mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
                if (item==2) mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.ITALIC);
                if (item==3) mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                editor1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CustomizeFont.this).edit();
                 editor1.putString("Default_Font1", String.valueOf(item));
                editor1.apply();

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
});
```

I can change the font but when i restart the activity it goes back to the original normal font... the problem is because of this line `mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);`

I need to set the `TypeFace.NORMAL` to `Default_Font1` But not accepting... what should I do?

Comment: `item` is number. `String.valueOf(item)` is still that number. You probably wanted `list[item]`. Also, think about what this does at the start: `mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to set the textview to Default_Font1 But not accepting... what should I do?

You need to `setTypeface`  in your `button` based on you values getting from `SharedPreferences`

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
mDefaultFont1 = mSharedPreferences1.getString("Default_Font1","0");
if (mDefaultFont1.equals("0")) {
    mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(), Typeface.NORMAL);
} else if (mDefaultFont1.equals("1")) {
    mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD);
} else if (mDefaultFont1.equals("2")) {
    mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(), Typeface.ITALIC);
} else if (mDefaultFont1.equals("3")) {
    mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
}

mButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final String[] list = new String[]{"Normal", "Bold", "Italic", "Bold ITalic"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CustomizeFont.this);
    builder.setTitle("Make your selection");
    builder.setItems(list, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (item==0) mButton1.setTypeface(null);
            if (item==1) mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
            if (item==2) mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.ITALIC);
            if (item==3) mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            editor1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CustomizeFont.this).edit();
             editor1.putString("Default_Font1", String.valueOf(item));
            editor1.apply();

        }
    });
    builder.show();
 }
 });
```

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: i dont think u understood my problem... the problem isnt with this part of the code... i have no issues with the aler dialogs... my problem is these 2 lines of code 

 mDefaultFont1 = mSharedPreferences1.getString("Default_Font1","Normal");
 mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);

Comment: Because i set the button to a font but when i restart activity it runs the code of mButton.setTypeface.Normal and sets it to normal again

Comment: @EmiliaJames i understand your question have a look my updated answer

Comment: Still not working,,,, i guess u went wrong... u set mDefaultFont1 to "0" in the 1st line and ur checking whethr it is 1 or 2 or 3... how is it possible when u hav set it to 0? i guess u need to change that first line

Comment: @EmiliaJames No that `"0"` is default value  of your `Default_Font1` if you have not set any value in `Default_Font1` than it will return `0`

Comment: Hey... it workedd... omg... thanks a ton dude... ur my hero lol

Comment: @EmiliaJames welcome happy to help you BTW nice Compliment

Comment: when i click on the button and set it to some other font it changes instantly but when i change the font to normal it doesn't change till i refresh the page... any idea why???

Comment: @EmiliaJames I didn't understand properly

Comment: When i change the font of the button to bold or italic or bold italic... it changes as soon as i click on the alert dialog... but when i click on NORMAL it doesn;t change until i refresh the page... why is it so?

Comment: @EmiliaJames again welome happy to helop you

Answer (score 0):

try this .

```
editor.putInt("fontCode",mButton1.getTypeFace().getStyle());
```

and then use it as normal shared prefrence

Comment: you will save style code using this in sharedprefrences and then you can use that style codeto change button style from sharedPrefrences

Answer (score 0):

```
mDefaultFont1 = mSharedPreferences1.getString("Default_Font1","Normal");
mButton1.setTypeface(mButton1.getTypeface(),Typeface.NORMAL);
```

This logic is completely wrong, keep in mind that you're saving int values in preferences (0, 1, 2, 3), but first you load it as if it was string with default value "normal".

In the second line you're setting the typeface for the button, but taking current typeface from same button, so what you get? No change.

Instead of that, I suggest something like this:

```
mDefaultFont1 = mSharedPreferences1.getInt("Default_Font1",0);
mButton1.setTypeface(mDefaultFont1);
```

And save the preference like this:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    int defaultTypeface = 0;
    if (item==0) defaultTypeface = Typeface.NORMAL;
    if (item==1) defaultTypeface = Typeface.BOLD;
    if (item==2) defaultTypeface = Typeface.ITALIC;
    if (item==3) defaultTypeface = Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC;
    mButton1.setTypeface(defaultTypeface);
    editor1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(CustomizeFont.this).edit();
    editor1.putInt("Default_Font1", defaultTypeface);
    editor1.apply();
```

}

Note, my code might be bit wrong, since I did write it from memory and didn't check if it's really fine.

Comment: Getting this error - https://ibb.co/jwzcm8
on the line 
        mDefaultFont1 = mSharedPreferences1.getInt("Default_Font1",0);

Comment: Sorry, saving the preference it must be editor1.putInt(...) instead of putString. I update my comment.